# iOS | Swift | Handling Daylight Saving Time

Tags: ios, swift, timezone, dst

For the first time I got an opportunity to handle Daylight saving time dates (both 23 and 25 hours in DST start and end date). Basically I am getting GMT dates from server that I need to plot on a graph. This has to consider daylight saving time rollover. I do have confusion on how to consider DST here ? I know that when DST starts then one loose an hour (2-3am on a 23 hour day) and when DST ends then one gains an hour (2-3am on a 25 hour day). I want to know if on a given DST day (start or end) do I need to shift the dates by 1 hour when the date is on same day but after 2-3am duration ? Any other considerations that I have to make here ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: See the documentation for `NSTimeZone`.